# Directory nonexistent Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Создал пользователя через консоль и так же создал ему папку. В чём может быть проблема и как её решить?

```
$ ls -l /home/
итого 12
drwxr-x--- 6 nas-scanner root 4096 июн 26 15:32 nas-scanner
$ ls -l /home/nas-scanner
итого 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nas-scanner nas-scanner    4 июн 26 15:32 123.txt
drwxrwxrwx 2 nas-scanner nas-scanner 4096 июн 26 13:37 scanner
 echo "123" >> /home/nas-sacanner/scanner/123/123    
-sh: 15: cannot create /home/nas-sacanner/scanner/123/123: Directory nonexistent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сделать запись в директорию `123`, которой не существует. Сделайте так:

```
$ echo "123" >> /home/nas-scanner/scanner/123.txt
```

если вы ходите записать в файл `123.txt` в директории `scanner`или

```
$ echo "123" >> /home/nas-scanner/scanner/123
```

если вы ходите записать в файл `123` в директории `scanner`

Или, если всё-таки надо записать в директорию `123`, предварительно её создайте:

```
$ mkdir /home/nas-scanner/scanner/123
$ echo "123" >> /home/nas-scanner/scanner/123/123
```

UPD. Исправил `nas-sacanner` на `nas-scanner`

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, команда либо создаёт файл и добавляет в него исходный текст, либо просто добавляет исходный текст. Можете проверить у себя на виртуальной машине. Файлы в linux не обязательно имеют расширение.

Comment: @shaman888, дело в том, что команда `echo` не видит отсутствующую директорию `123`, именно из-за этого ошибка.

Comment: я всё же попробовал с корректными путями и с указанием расширения, однако это не помогло. В тех случаях когда папка отсутствует, отображается соответствующая ошибка. echo "123" >> 1232312/123
bash: 1232312/123: Нет такого файла или каталога

Comment: Давайте так: `ls -l /home/nas-sacanner/scanner/`, а потом `echo "123" >> /home/nas-sacanner/scanner/123`. Покажите, что получается.

Comment: ls -l /home/nas-scanner/scanner/
итого 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 nas-scanner nas-scanner 4096 июн 26 15:40 123
echo "123" >> /home/nas-sacanner/scanner/123
-sh: 6: cannot create /home/nas-sacanner/scanner/123: Directory nonexistent
echo "123" >> /home/nas-sacanner/scanner/123/123.txt
-sh: 9: cannot create /home/nas-sacanner/scanner/123/123.txt: Directory nonexistent

Comment: Конечно у вас нет директории `nas-sacanner`, но у вас есть `nas-scanner`.

Comment: действительно опечатка, однако ошибка осталась.
echo "123" >> /nas-scanner/scanner/123/123.txt
-sh: 16: cannot create /nas-scanner/scanner/123/123.txt: Directory nonexistent
Введём тоже самое под другим пользователем 

echo "123" >> /nas-scanner/scanner/123/123.txt
-bash: /nas-scanner/scanner/123/123.txt: Нет такого файла или каталога
как видите ответ разный, во втором случае действительно каталог отсутствует

Comment: `ls -l /home/nas-sacanner/scanner/123` ?

Comment: $ ls -l /home/nas-sacanner/scanner/123
ls: невозможно получить доступ к '/home/nas-sacanner/scanner/123': Нет такого файла или каталога
$ ls -l /home/nas-scanner/scanner/123
итого 0

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61105/discussion-between-zombic-and-shaman888).